# How can i change psuedo-code to NuSMV code?

Tags: model, logic, model-checking, nusmv

My professor decide to give us math student a code to change into NuSMV and i can't seem to find anywhere else for help and i read the textbook it like 6 pages only and only describe what certain property does. Module main is an example of NuSMV code  and he said to use that format example to write the psuedo code. 
I don't know how to write the while loop and set what to be true? and would flag1 be a state and turn be also another state?

```
 while(true) do
  flag1 := true
    while flag2 do
     if turn=2
       flag1 := false;
       wait until turn = 1;
       flag1 := true
  Critical section
  turn := 2
  flag1 := false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to model *Dekker/Dijkstra's algorithm* for mutual exclusion among two processes.

The **steps** of your interest, based on your question, should only be **1-4**. I added some more to provide a more complete picture of what can be achieved with **NuSMV**.

I used a slightly different version of the same algorithm, though the underlying idea is the same.

---

**IDEA:** there exists a methodology for converting *pseudo-code* into a *NuSMV* model:

1. Label the **entry** and **exit** point of each statement in your code:

   ```
   --     void p(iflag, turn, id) {
   -- l0:   while(true) do
   -- l1:     flag := true
   -- l2:     while iflag do
   -- l3:       if turn != id
   -- l4:         flag := false;
   -- l5:         wait until turn = id;
   -- l6:         flag := true
   -- l7:     // Critical section
   -- l8:     turn := 1 - id
   -- l9:     flag := false;
   --     }
   ```

   Note that some statements, e.g. `while iflag do`, might have more than one *exit* point depending on the value of the *guard*: if `iflag` is true, then the *exit* point is **l3**, otherwise the *exit* point is **l7**.
2. Create a corresponding **module** that takes the same *inputs* and has a *state* variable which evaluates to the newly introduced *labels*.

   ```
   MODULE p(iflag, turn, id)
   VAR
     state : { l0, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, error };
     flag : boolean;
   ```

   Here, notice that i added the special state *error*. This is only to ensure that during the definition the transition relation for *state* we are not leaving out any correct transition step. In general, it should be omitted as it does not belong to the original code.
3. Define the transition relation for *state*:

   ```
   ASSIGN
     init(state) := l0;
     next(state) := case
       state = l0              : l1;
       state = l1              : l2;
       state = l2 & iflag      : l3;
       state = l2 & !iflag     : l7;
       state = l3 & turn != id : l4;
       state = l3 & turn = id  : l2;
       state = l4              : l5;
       state = l5 & turn != id : l5;
       state = l5 & turn = id  : l6;
       state = l6              : l2;
       state = l7              : l8;
       state = l8              : l9;
       state = l9              : l0;
       TRUE                    : error; -- if you match this then the above
                                        -- description of transitions are incomplete
     esac;
   ```

   As you can see, I simply connected every *entry point* with the corresponding *exit point*. Moreover, wherever more than one *exit point* is defined for a given *entry point* I also added other *state conditions* to determine what *line* is executed next.
4. Add the transition relation for *flag*:

   ```
   init(flag) := FALSE;
   next(flag) := case
     state = l1 | state = l6 : TRUE;
     state = l4 | state = l9 : FALSE;
     TRUE                    : flag;
   esac;
   ```
5. Add some definitions to identify which sections of code the process is executing:

   ```
   DEFINE
     critical_section := (state = l7);
     trying_section := (state = l1 | state = l2 | state = l3 |
                        state = l4 | state = l5 | state = l6);
   ```
6. Create a **main module** which creates two instances of **p**:

   ```
   MODULE main ()
   VAR
     turn : {0, 1};
     p1   : p(p2.flag, turn, 0);
     p2   : p(p1.flag, turn, 1);

   ASSIGN
     init(turn) := 0;
     next(turn) := case
       p1.state = l8 : 1;
       p2.state = l8 : 0;
       TRUE          : turn;
     esac;
   ```
7. Add some very *typical* **mutual exclusion properties** to be verified by the model checker:

   ```
     --*-- PROPERTIES --*--

   -- Safety: two processes are never in the critical section at the same time
   CTLSPEC AG !(p1.critical_section & p2.critical_section);

   -- Liveness: if a process is in the trying section, then sooner or later
   --           it will access the critical section.
   CTLSPEC AG (p1.trying_section -> AF p1.critical_section);

   -- Absence of Starvation
   CTLSPEC ! EF AG (p1.trying_section & p2.trying_section);

   -- Never in Error State 
   CTLSPEC AG !(p1.state = error);
   ```
8. Run the tool

   ```
   ~$ NuSMV -int
   ```

   and check that all properties are verified:

   ```
   NuSMV > reset; read_model -i dekker.smv; go; check_property
   -- specification AG !(p1.critical_section & p2.critical_section)  is true
   -- specification AG (p1.trying_section -> AF p1.critical_section)  is true
   -- specification !(EF (AG (p1.trying_section & p2.trying_section)))  is true
   -- specification AG !(p1.state = error)  is true
   ```

---

**NOTES:**

1. If you look closely at steps **1** and **3**, several states look redundant. For instance, it is always possible to collapse contiguous states that have only one entry and exit points. I'll leave this to you as an exercise.
2. Notice that I used the synchronous composition of modules for simplicity. In practice the verification would be more meaningful by letting the two processes to be run asynchronously. However, this would require making the model more complex than your question really required, and it is thus beyond the scope of my answer.
3. If you would like to learn more about *NuSMV*, you can take a look at its [documentation](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/tutorial/index.html) or look at the second part of this [course](http://www.patricktrentin.com/pages/fm2016.html).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I UNDERSTAND THIS BETTER THAN THE TUTORIAL. SO in general it basically like states that jump to the next state  which is basically the instruction and i know that there is more complex way to run this more smoothly but i couldn't understand how to do it so this helps alot!

Comment: @Darkflame you are welcome, if the answer solved your issue then I would invite you to mark it as accepted. Otherwise, if you need further assistance, feel free to integrate your question or drop a comment here.

Comment: Is it possible for me to put 2 commands into 1 state  like  state = l0              : l1;
    state = l1              : l2;  it would become  state = l0 & state = l1 ; l2

Comment: @Darkflame `state = l0 : l1; state = l1 : l2` is not equivalent to `state = l0 & state = l1 : l2`. In fact, `state = l0 & state = l1` is a trivially false condition, since variable `state` can only have one value at any given time. What you can do is to merge labels `l0` and `l1` into a unique label `l01`, by substituting all their occurrences within the model (see note #1). Notice that a false condition is simply ignored, and thus NuSMV would then evaluate the next condition in the *case/esac* block of code.

Comment: hey Can you help with more CLTSPEC what AG and all the other stands for  and i wrote the code but i keep getting line 4 syntax error when running it do you mind checking it?